# Threejs: The Questions about Geometry

Tags: three.js

I want to create a group of geometry like the picture below, how to draw AxisHelper for each geometry like picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PEhE.png)? And to combine the geometry, how can I set the location for each geometry? By using `**.position.set()`?

[image: the side view with wireframe]

Comment: Are you familiar with object-hierarchies? In three.js you can add an objects to any other object to model how parts move together. So if you do something like `leg.add(foot); body.add(leg);` you will have the foot moving along with any motion of the leg. Same for `AxisHelper`: just add an axis-helper to any object.

Comment: How to determine the relative position for each part, like body and leg? By setting the absolute position for each part?

Comment: You would specify all positions relative to their parent, so if the parent is at (1,0,0) and child.position is (2,1,0) it would end up being rendered at (3,1,0).